# Bend (curve) the path the same amount in photoshop

Tags: photoshop

Hi I am using Photoshop pen toll to make a path like the photo below.

[image]

I am trying to make points A ,B ,C ,D and E with exact same amount of curving (bending).
Is there any way to do that ?
Is there a  place (input text) where I can add number expresses the bending amount?
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst this may be better answered on [graphic design stack exchange](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/), I'll give you the benefit of the doubt:

This is actually a non-trivial problem in code as Photoshop script supports paths so badly.

Your best (and faster option) is to use guides and snap the bezier path points to the guides making sure the left and right halves are the same: Drag out the points with CTRL and ALT held down and then release those keys and press down SHIFT so the curve snaps to 45 degrees.

As far as I'm aware, there is no option to put any numeric values in paths within Photoshop.

[image: path on guides]